# Can I pull all members of a private base into the public scope of an inheriting class?

Tags: c++, c++17, using, private-inheritance

When inheriting privately from a base class, I can say `public: using Base::member;` to make that (non-private) member public within the inheriting class. Is there some way to expand this to get all the members at once? The context I want this in is a CTRP setting I'm using to avoid code duplication.

Example:

```
struct Base {
  int foo();
  void bar();
  // ...
}

struct A : private Base {
  using Base::*; // not correct syntax

  // should have the effect of
  using Base::foo;
  using Base::bar;
  // ...
};
```

Even better would be if I could select only Base's public members, but not its protected or private members. This would just be a bonus.

Comment: Nope, there's nothing in C++ like this.

Comment: Why can't you use `public` inheritance?

Comment: @janekb04 Defensive design?

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I'm not sure how would using `private` inheritance be more defensive if you plan to achieve the same effect as with `public` inheritance anyway. If you're defending against changes to `Base`, than inheriting from it is already a cause of potential ABI breaks when `Base` is modified. You could use composition and store a pointer to `Base` if you're concerned with that, though admittedly in that case you would have to provide wrappers for its members manually. Do you want to prevent upcasting do `Base`?

Comment: @janekb04 I suppose the most pressing would be slicing. But I suppose there are many more design issues.